# payment gateway call back url data fetching error

Tags: angular, http-post, payment-gateway, form-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uny1f.png)

buildesk

how to get call back URL(post methord) data from angular application i cant acces the output form data in angular 13

please help me

buildesk

how to get call back URL(post methord) data from angular application i cant acces the output form data in angular 13

please help me

Comment: please help me how to get callback url (post method) data in angular 13

Comment: Please format your question correctly.